# Search for multiple possible param values

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

At the moment I have a form in which the user can input price per person and/or duration and/or team_size. What I would like to accomplish is to retrieve all records from a table that match the user input and for this I set scope in the model:

```
scope :filter_by_team_size, -> (team_size) { where("team_size = ?", team_size) }
scope :filter_by_duration, -> (duration) { where("duration = ?", duration) }
scope :filter_by_price, -> (price) { where("price = ?", price) }
```

And then in the controller use that again to retrieve the records by doing so:

```
@experiences = policy_scope(Experience).order(team_size: :desc).geocoded.filter_by_team_size(params[:team_size]) if params[:team_size].present?
@experiences = policy_scope(Experience).order(duration: :desc).geocoded.filter_by_duration(params[:duration]) if params[:duration].present?
@experiences = policy_scope(Experience).order(price: :desc).geocoded.filter_by_price(params[:price]) if params[:price].present?
```

However, this only gives me only the records for which the first input value matches but ignores all other values. Additionally, when you are viewing the search results and use the filter again it should apply the filter only for the records it found already.

Any suggestion on how to solve this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using the select method on the records?  So if you have `@experiences` you can apply something like `@expereinces.select {|e| e.duration == params[:duration]}` and so on?  Might help you continually filter things out. https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/select

Comment: @RockwellRice bad idea. That will load all the records out the database which will work if you have a trivial amount of records but will be really slow or outright crash the server if you have a lot of data. He is actually on the right path building scopes with where to filter the data.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is to use a virtual model that handles binding parameters to and from the form:

```
class SearchQuery
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  attribute :team_size, :integer
  attribute :duration
  attribute :price
end
```

You can then setup the form:

```
<%= form_with(model: (@search_query || SearchQuery.new), url: '/experiences', method: :get) %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :team_size %>
    <%= f.number_field :team_size %>
  </div>
  # ..
<% end %>
```

And then you can just bind the params to the model with `ActionController::Parameters#permit` just like you would with a normal ActiveRecord model:

```
class ExperiencesController
  before_action :set_search_query, only: :index, if: ->{ params[:search_query].present? }
  # ...

  def index
    @experiences = if @search_query 
      @search_query.build_scope(policy_scope(Experience))
    else
      policy_scope(Experience)
    end.geocoded
  end

  private
  def set_search_query
     @search_query = SearchQuery.new(search_query_params)
  end

  def search_query_params
     params.fetch(:search_query).permit(:team_size, :duration, :price)
  end
end
```

This loopback will make the form stateful just like your normal CRUD forms. We have not actually implemented `#build_scope` yes so lets do so:

```
class SearchQuery
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  attribute :team_size, :integer
  attribute :duration
  attribute :price

  def build_scope(base_scope)
    compacted_attributes = attributes.reject { value.nil? || value.empty? }
    compacted_attributes.each_with_object(base_scope) do |(k,v), base|
      if base.respond_to? "filter_by_#{k}"
        # lets you customize the logic with a scope
        base.send("filter_by_#{k}", v) # the scope is responsible for ordering
      else
        # convention over configuration!
        base.where(Hash[k,v]).order(Hash[k,:desc])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Since this uses convention over configuration you can get rid of those pointless scopes in your model.